# sql username and password

Tags: civicrm.settings.php, mysql-5.7

I have installed civicrm bitnami stack on google cloud.

I need to connect sql database with tableau for data visualisation. How can i get the server, port, username and password for this connection.

Answer (score 1):

- Connect to [Bitnami using SSH](https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/faq/get-started/connect-ssh/).
- Find `civicrm.settings.php` with `find . -name civicrm.settings.php`.  You can probably speed things along by first navigating to `apps/civicrm/htdocs`.
- In the file, look for the line that defines `CIVICRM_DSN`, which can be interpreted as follows:

```
    define('CIVICRM_DSN', 'mysql://user:password@host/database?new_link=true');
```

According to the [Bitnami CiviCRM docs](https://bitnami.com/stack/civicrm/README.txt) the port is 3006.  I assume that's correct and not a typo for "3306".

Comment: I figured out the credentials using bitnami docs. The mySQL doc says the default username is root, and the password is the Admin Password (Temporary) that we see in google cloud console where Admin URL, site address are listed. I did SSH from there and able to connect with mysql using root and temp password. The port is actually 3306, i checked the docs. Problem is what to enter in Server/Host in Tableau ? Second, in CIVICRM_DSN, what is username and password.